# DLQ on Failed Task in Step Function

Tags: aws-step-functions, dead-letter

In case of Failed Task in step function, after trying with retry strategy, is there a way I can put these Failed tasks in some DLQ or something like that so that someone can monitor these messages later and redrive them after fixing the issue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes you can catch the error after retry and send it to SQS. Here is an example.

```
{
   "StartAt": "GetMyRecords",
   "States": {
      "GetMyRecords": {
         "Type": "Task",
         "Resource": "<resource arn>",
         "TimeoutSeconds": 80,
         "Retry": [
            {
               "ErrorEquals": [
                  "CustomError"
               ],
               "IntervalSeconds": 300,
               "MaxAttempts": 10,
               "BackoffRate": 1.1
            }
         ],
         "Catch": [
            {
               "ErrorEquals": [
                  "CustomError"
               ],
               "Next": "SendToSQS",
               "ResultPath": "$.error"
            }
         ],
         "End": true
      },
      "SendToSQS": {
         "Type": "Task",
         "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::sqs:sendMessage",
         "Parameters": {
            "QueueUrl": "https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/123456789012/myQueue",
            "MessageBody.$": "$.input.message",
            "MessageAttributes": {
               "MyAttribute1": {
                  "DataType": "String",
                  "StringValue": "Value of attribute 1"
               },
               "MyAttribute1": {
                  "DataType": "String",
                  "StringValue": "Value of attribute 2"
               }
            }
         },
         "End": true
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just one thing you can redrive any step function from the failed step only. So if you try to redrive in this case, your step function's last step is SendToSQS which is not failed. And even if it is Failed, you want to redrive from GetMyRecords, so I don't think this is an apt solution.